# White spots growing on shrub

Tags: diseases

I've recently noticed some white spots growing on the branches of the shrub in my garden. May I ask what they are and what should I do about them? Thank you in advance.
[image: whitespots]

Answer (score 2):

Its just lichen, not a problem. Search this site for previous answers on this.

Comment: Thank you Polypipe.